# form token caching joomla on varnish cache

Tags: joomla, token, varnish

The Joomla token is cached by Varnish Caching Server. I know this is a process to protect the site from CSRF attacks. I temporarily disabled the token checking from the code base. However, I'd like to enable them and permanently solve the issue. Can someone help me out in this regard.

Comment: I think a page like that could send a `no-store` in `cache-control` and then varnish would respect that and not cache it.

Comment: Will investigate that..

Comment: J-D did you find solution on this? If yes please share it.